# Other radical symbol in other counrty

Tags: symbols

My teacher said that we need to search for a radical symbol used in other country and I already searched it in every site but I can't find one. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the symbol? Also, which country are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! What is a radical symbol? How does it look like? In which field is it used?

Comment: @clemens: I assume the sqrt symbol √

Comment: @Christian interesting: I immediately thought of the radical dot in chemistry :)

Comment: @clemens: I've the deep impression that you have some loose connections to chemistry :-P  -- Well, I thought of that too, but in Mathematics √  is sometimes called radical too

Comment: Isn't this a math.stackexchange problem (if radical means root)? Anyway, I know historically ℞ (`\textrecipe`) was used as radical symbol, stands for radix.

Comment: Are you sure she didn't say "radix"?

If so radix (in the US and most English speaking countries) is the decimal point (.) used to separate the integer part from the fractional part of a real number. Commas (,) are used for separating groups of three digits in the integer part.

But a large number of countries it is reversed; they use commas to separate the fractional part and the decimal to separate digits of an integer.